# Problem with html,style,padding and div section (I think)

Tags: stylesheet, html

I have the code below, which works lovely and does EXACTLY what I want it to do, except the header section is a a line down from the top of the div section and I would like it butted to the top.. is there anything I can do about this ?

Thanks

```
<div id = "Side1"  style="width: 175px;height:210px;overflow:hidden;background-color: #AAAAAA;border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px;" >
                <h4>Articles</h4>
                <%=SideBar()%>
                </div>
                <br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're seeing default padding/margins from you h4 tag.  Try resetting them:

```
h4 {
   margin-top: 0;
   padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks pat, can write the code to animate div sections, but style sheets e.t.c go way over my head ... cheers